# How do you set cookie policy in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, python-requests, zeep

I am using python 3.8.  I am trying to use the Zeep library to consume a company SOAP resource.  The SOAP service is old and will not be updated anytime soon.  One of the issues with this is the service sets a "session ID" in a response cookie.  It sets the, now obsolete, `set-cookie2` header.

```
    from requests import Session
    from zeep import Client, Settings
    from zeep.cache import SqliteCache
    from zeep.transports import Transport

    my_session = Session()
    my_settings = Settings(strict=False)
    my_cache = SqliteCache()
    my_url = 'https://lists.mycompany.com/lists/wsdl'

    client = Client(
        my_url,
        transport=Transport(
            session=my_session,
            cache=my_cache
        ),
        settings=my_settings
    )
    ...
```

I can see the cookie object in `my_session`.  It is a `RequestsCookieJar` and I can not figure out how to set the cookie policy values.  In the pycharm debugger I can see that `my_session.cookies` has "Protected Attributes" and one of those is `_policy` which is a `DefaultCookiePolicy` object.  I can see that `hide_cookie2` is False (the default and what I need) but that `rfc2965` is also False and needs to be set to True.

In the `RequestsCookieJar` class I see the `get_policy()` method but nothing to set policy.  I am missing a linkage somewhere.  How do I set the cookie policy for the whole app or per request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well,
you can override the `DefaultCookiePolicy` properties like this:

```
from http.cookiejar import DefaultCookiePolicy
from requests import Session

myCookiePolicy=DefaultCookiePolicy(rfc2965=True)

my_session = Session()
my_session.cookies.set_policy(policy=myCookiePolicy)
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you.  It does help.  However, over the weekend, I learned that there are two issues: 1) Zeep does not pass session cookies into the `requests` `post` method; and, 2) `requests` has a long standing known issue in that it does not actually copy cookie **policies** for outbound requests -- apparently that is a complicated thing.

Comment: welcome. to be able to help others, please accept this answer as it resolve the issue stated in question. hope its ok.